# Need of using 'r' before path-name while reading a csv file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

a newbie here.
Could someone tell me why do we use an 'r' in some cases before the path name in the following function?:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"Path_name")
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In Python, backslash is used to signify special characters.

For example, `"hello\nworld"` -- the `\n` means a newline. Try printing it.

Path names on Windows tend to have backslashes in them. But we want them to mean actual backslashes, not special characters.

r stands for "raw" and will cause backslashes in the string to be interpreted as actual backslashes rather than special characters.

e.g. `r"hello\nworld"` literally means the characters `"hello\nworld"`. Again, try printing it.

More info is in the Python docs, it's a good idea to search them for questions like these.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Answer (score 4):

A raw string will handle back slashes in most cases, such as these two examples:

```
In [11]:
r'c:\path'

Out[11]:
'c:\\path'
```

However, if there is a trailing slash then it will break:

```
In [12]:
r'c:\path\'

  File "<ipython-input-12-9995c7b1654a>", line 1
    r'c:\path\'
               ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Forward slashes doesn't have this problem:

```
In [13]:
r'c:/path/'

Out[13]:
'c:/path/'
```

The safe and portable method is to use forward slashes always and if building a string for a full path to use [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) to correctly handle building a path that will work when the code is executed on different operating systems:

```
In [14]:
import os
path = 'c:/'
folder = 'path/'
os.path.join(path, folder)

Out[14]:
'c:/path/'
```

Answer (score 2):

- This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42655010) by [Denziloe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5506894/denziloe) does a perfect job of explaining why `r` may precede a path string.

  - `r'C:\Users\username'` works
  - `r'C:\Users\username\'` does not, because the trailing `\` escapes the `'`.

    - `r'C:\Users\username\' + file`, where `file = 'test.csv'` also won't work
    - Results in `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`
- `pandas` methods that will read a file, such as [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) will accept a `str` or a [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) object for a file path.
- If you need to iterate through a list of file names, you can add them with an [`f-string`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

  - `num = 6`, `f'I have {num} files'` interprets as `'I have 6 files'`, is an example of using an `f-string`.

```py
import pandas as pd

files = ['test1.csv', 'test2.csv', 'test3.csv']

df_list = list()
for file in files:
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(rf'C:\Users\username\{file}'))  # path with f-string

df = pd.concat(df_list)
```