# os.listdir works in console but fails in a script

Tags: python

My script uses os.listdir to get a list of directories to use later for batch analysis.

when running

```
mypath='//home//user//Documents//data'
datalist=os.listdir(mypath)
```

in console, I get the correct answer.

However, when I use the same code as a part of the script, python falls over on the `datalist` line

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '//home//user//Documents//data//'
```

Comment: Your code does not fit the error message. One has slashes the other has backslashes.

Comment: Are you sure that this path exists? Also, if you use forward slash(/), you shuoldn't double it. Just use `mypath = '/home/user/Documents/data'` To prevent confusion, use "r" such as `mypath = r'/home/user/Documents/data'` or `mypath = r'\home\user\Documents\data'`

Comment: edited now, apologies

Comment: There is a typo in "documents" being returned by your error message. Have you spelt the path correctly?

Comment: usint mypath=r'\home\user\Documents\data' worked! what does that do?

Comment: Are you using Cygwin or MSYS2 by chance? What are your platform details?

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19034895/6900838):

> The `r'..'` string modifier causes the `'..'` string to be interpreted
>   **literally**. That means, `r'My\Path\Without\Escaping'` will evaluate to
>   `'My\Path\Without\Escaping'` - without causing the backslash to escape
>   characters. The prior is equivalent to `'My\\Path\\Without\\Escaping'`
>   string, but without the raw modifier.

And there is an explanation with a simple example at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42655010/6900838).

So use

```
mypath = r'\home\user\Documents\data'
```